# Question with big "EDIT:" in the body. What should be done in this case?

Tags: discussion, questions

I recently found [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/12020/199843) that has a big **EDIT:** area in the body, where the OP says something that should be a comment on the accepted answer and asks a completely separate question.

[image]

What should be done in this part of the question? Edited with this area removed and nothing else?

Comment: I found [When is “EDIT”/“UPDATE” appropriate in a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127639/384246) and [Is it recommended to notify the answer “Edits” with an heading followed by the edit content?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230692/384246) on Meta Stack Exchange, but they say nothing about comments on the body of the question